# Remove styling in the ::after selector

Tags: html, css

I'm having problems with removing the style from a piece of text under `::after` selector and I were unable to find a solution from the internet. The design is basically a linear Gradient towards the left side.

```css
.txt {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #E27822,#E2224C);
   -webkit-background-clip: text;
   -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
   font-weight: bold ;
}
.txt::after {
   content: " - More Sample Text";
   background: none;
   -webkit-background-clip: none !important;
   -webkit-text-fill-color: none !important;
   color: green;
}
```

```html
<span class="txt">Sample Text</span>
<p>The "<b>More Sample Text</b>" should be coloured <span style="color: green;"><b>Green</b></span>.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

[`-webkit-text-fill-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-fill-color) only accepts colors, and `none` is not a proper color.

It seems you want to reset to the initial value, which is [`currentColor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#currentColor_keyword).

```css
.txt {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #E27822, #E2224C);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.txt::after {
  content: " - More Sample Text";
  color: green;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: currentColor;
}
```

```html
<span class="txt">Sample Text</span>
<p>The "<b>More Sample Text</b>" should be coloured <span style="color: green;"><b>Green</b></span>.</p>
```

Some minor reminiscences of the old background may still appear around the text, probably due to antialiasing. To prevent that, you can add a white background.

```css
.txt {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #E27822, #E2224C);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.txt::after {
  content: " - More Sample Text";
  -webkit-text-fill-color: green;
  background: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<span class="txt">Sample Text</span>
<p>The "<b>More Sample Text</b>" should be coloured <span style="color: green;"><b>Green</b></span>.</p>
```

Comment: The `currentColor` colour is being overlayed on the current style. I want to remove it completely so it is pure Green.

Comment: Overlayed by what? It's pure green for me.

Comment: There is a thin Border around the Green Text. The border is definitely the old style.

Comment: OK, I see it now. You can cover it with a white background.

Comment: Now here is another problem. If the background of the page is some other colour, there would be a white rectangle behind the text under `::after`.

Comment: It will probably be easier if you just take the pseudo-element out of flow with `position: absolute`.

Comment: That is not quite possible as I am creating a Template in a Wikia which will be posted in various pages.

Comment: If the width is know, you can use `background-size` to limit the gradient. Or wrap the text in an inner container.

Comment: I have access to CSS only, the HTML is already done and is restricted.